# Group Multiple Columns by a Single Column -- Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am trying to group the average of columns **B** and **C** by column **A**. I am unsure how to accomplish this using the groupby function:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame({'B' : df.groupby(['A'])['B'].mean()}).reset_index()
```

Because I can only figure out how to find the average and group a single column by another. If this is my *Current Dataframe*:

```
A  B   C

0  70  12
0  20  14
0  46  11
1  25  9
2  86  2
2  14  6
```

This is my *Expected Outcome*. Grouping all like values of **A** together, corresponding values in **B** and **C** are averaged in their respective columns:

```
A  B     C

0  45.3  12.3
1  25    9
2  50    4
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
df.groupby('A').mean()
Out[339]: 
           B          C
A                      
0  45.333333  12.333333
1  25.000000   9.000000
2  50.000000   4.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Although `.mean()` is the most obvious solution, you can also aggregate the results:

```
>>> df.groupby('A').agg('mean')
           B          C
A                      
0  45.333333  12.333333
1  25.000000   9.000000
2  50.000000   4.000000
```

Using [`.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#aggregation), you can aggregate multiple functions simultaneously, e.g.:

```
>>> df.groupby('A').agg(['mean', 'std'])
           B                     C          
        mean        std       mean       std
A                                           
a  45.333333  25.006666  12.333333  1.527525
b  25.000000        NaN   9.000000       NaN
c  50.000000  50.911688   4.000000  2.828427
```